# Permission denial on BroadCast SMS intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

can my activity broadcast this intent from itself

> Intent i = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
>
> sendBroadcast(i);

I am able to send this broadcast and receive it back (from a broadcast receiver setup in the application) , but this is not a global broadcast , i.e. it is not received by  the default SMS application. 
furthermore i am getting this error in the logcat

> Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent
>   {
>   act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
>   } from com.smartanuj.scale (pid=3572,
>   uid=10029) requires
>   android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS due
>   to receiver
>   com.android.mms/com.android.mms.transaction.PrivilegedSmsReceiver

I have already specified

```
 <uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

in my manifest file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only applications signed with the system key may broadcast the arrival of new SMS messages.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to have the BROADCAST_SMS privilege, and to generate the PDU by yourself. Then it works. You can find a summary here: http://blog.dev001.net/post/14085892020/android-generate-incoming-sms-from-within-your-app (second part, "Doing it by generating a SMS_RECEIVED broadcast").

Comment: The example can be found there. Which specific part do you want? I can also send you the whole Android project as an archive if you want.

Comment: thankyou,i need the whole android project,my email  wp19831014@gmail.com very thank you

Comment: I would also like the whole android project.  I've had difficulties getting the GsmAlphabet part properly configured...at least that's what I think the problem is.  I actually posted a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592443/sms-broadcasting-from-my-app) concerning this topic that I could give you credit for answering -- chadkuehn@gmail.com